# PHP HMAC-SHA1 function not returning "=" as padding character?

Tags: php, oauth, hmacsha1

I am trying to produce an HMAC-SHA1 signature to request an access token and token secret from the Tumblr API. I am using the hmac_hash() function in PHP and my understanding is that the algorithm should produce an "=" as padding at the end of the signature, however the signature returned to me by the function never has that padding and I think that is why I keep receiving the following the message from Tumblr : "oauth_signature does not match expected value". 
I have tried using several online signature generators to test this and some produce the padding 
and some don't so I am a bit confused at this point.

Here is my code:

```
$params = array(
    'oauth_callback' => $callback,
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce' => $oauth_nonce,
    'oauth_ver' => $oauth_ver,
    'oauth_signature_method' => $signature_method,
    'oauth_timestamp' => $time
                        );

ksort($params);         
//--------------- build param string 
$params;
end($params);    // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
$lastkey = key($params); 
ksort($params);

$param_string;
foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
  $param_string .= rawurlencode(utf8_encode($k))."=".rawurlencode(utf8_encode($v));
  if($k != $lastkey) {
    $param_string .= "&";
            }
            };

// --------------- build signature base string
$base_string;
$base_string .= rawurlencode(utf8_encode($http_method))."&";
$base_string .= rawurlencode(utf8_encode($url))."&";
$base_string .= rawurlencode(utf8_encode($param_string));

//------------------ build signing key
$signing_key;
$signing_key .= rawurlencode(utf8_encode($consumer_secret))."&";

//------------------ build the signature 
$signature;
$signature = hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $signing_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change this:
$signature = hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $signing_key);

to this:
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $signing_key, true));